# Strange functioning with segments in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am currently working on a system with a particular architecture (not mine). In the main application folder, there is the common asset and 2 others folders (user and admin) with the same kind of asset, which give us this architecture :

- application

  - admin

    - config
    - controller
    - etc ...
  - user

    - config
    - controller
    - etc ...
  - controller
  - etc ...

In the root folder, there is 2 files : `user.php` and `admin.php` each having the same code than in the classical `index.php` except for the line

```
$application_folder = 'application/admin';
```

So far, the code is working... But I have found a strange reaction.
In my folder `admin`, under a controller, I am calling a method, which work except for one thing... the view are not correctly loaded.

In all other method I have this kind of code, with only one parameters :

```
public function results($param){
  $data = [];

  //some other code

  $this->load->view("election/header");
  $this->load->view("election/menu");
  $this->load->view("election/results", $data);
  $this->load->view("election/footer");
}
```

This is perfectly working, but when I had a second parameter, miraculously, the method didn't display anymore the header/menu/footer. Only the custom view `result`...
I also found that if I randomly add another parameter to the previews method `results` for exemple, the same kind of bug happens. The header/footer/menu aren't normally displayed anymore.
I guess there is a problem with the routing/htaccess or segment... but I can't put my finger on it...

Here is the root `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^kanri(/(.*))?$ admin.php?/$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user(/(.*))?$ user.php?/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the `admin/routing.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is it not loading header/menu/footer, or they are loaded, but with assets missmatch?

Comment: How can I check if it's the case?

Comment: Are your styles(css) and js files loaded correctly?

Comment: Okey... my bad... It's loaded but somehow, all the link are... broken? Css/Javascript/relative link are down.

Comment: That's what i meant. You could solve the problem using `<?php echo base_url('path to your css/js'); ?>`, you've to edit your header and footer. In your `config.php` you will find `$config['base_url']` it should be set to your domain(for example), including trailing slash `/`.

Comment: In both, there is the line `$config['base_url']` set...

Comment: I know it's set. Edit your header and footer like the example I gave you above.

Comment: But why it's working with one parameter but not with two or more? I mean, there is something like 30 pages already working... none with 2 parameters.

Comment: Edit your post with header code, I assume that it's looking for assets inside /parameter/css etc... You could check your console log.

Comment: Okey, so, yup...All the path have been set manually... Replacing it by the relative path using `site_url` seems to fix my problem. Thanks for your help. It was quite simple... Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to D. Dimitrov, the solution was simple. I just had to replace the relative path by using the `site_url()` function. I haven't totally understand the why but since it's working, it's all gud :>